# Pandas groupby and resample gives unusual result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have created a DataFrame with following data

```
Time            Source      Destination     User ID
1/1/20 12:00    1.2.3.4     5.6.7.8         a1
1/1/20 12:01    1.3.4.5     6.7.8.9         a2
1/1/20 12:02    1.3.4.5     7.2.3.4         a2
1/1/20 12:03    1.2.3.4     5.6.7.8         a1
1/1/20 12:04    1.6.3.4     5.6.7.8         a3
1/1/20 12:05    1.3.4.5     6.7.8.9         a2
1/1/20 12:06    1.6.5.4     7.2.3.4         a4
1/1/20 12:07    1.3.4.5     5.6.7.8         a2
1/1/20 12:08    1.3.4.5     6.7.8.9         a2
1/1/20 12:09    1.2.3.4     7.2.3.4         a1
1/1/20 12:10    1.6.3.4     5.6.7.8         a3
1/1/20 12:11    1.3.4.5     6.7.8.9         a2
1/1/20 12:12    1.6.5.4     7.2.3.4         a4
1/1/20 12:13    1.2.3.4     5.6.7.8         a1
1/1/20 12:14    1.3.4.5     6.7.8.9         a2
1/1/20 12:15    1.3.4.5     7.2.3.4         a2
```

I tried to use groupby with resample as below

```
df3 = df2.groupby( [ "Source", "Destination","User ID"]).resample('5T').size().to_frame(name = 'count').reset_index()
df3 = df3.set_index('Time')
df3 = df3.sort_index()
```

And I'm getting following result (pasted only for 1st two groups...)

```
Time            Source      Destination     User ID     count
1/1/2020 12:00  1.2.3.4     5.6.7.8         a1          2
1/1/2020 12:00  1.3.4.5     6.7.8.9         a2          1
1/1/2020 12:00  1.3.4.5     7.2.3.4         a2          1
1/1/2020 12:00  1.6.3.4     5.6.7.8         a3          1
1/1/2020 12:05  1.2.3.4     7.2.3.4         a1          1
1/1/2020 12:05  1.3.4.5     6.7.8.9         a2          2
1/1/2020 12:05  1.3.4.5     7.2.3.4         a2          0
1/1/2020 12:05  1.6.3.4     5.6.7.8         a3          0
1/1/2020 12:05  1.6.5.4     7.2.3.4         a4          1
1/1/2020 12:05  1.3.4.5     5.6.7.8         a2          1
1/1/2020 12:05  1.2.3.4     5.6.7.8         a1          0
```

My question is; why am I getting the rows with '0' count?

Example `1/1/2020 12:05 1.3.4.5     7.2.3.4         a2          0`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Python counters start at `0`. So instead of getting `1,2,3`, Python gives `0,1,2`. If that is an issue you can always just add 1 to each counter.

`1/1/2020 12:05 1.3.4.5     7.2.3.4         a2          0` is actually 1.